# Which variable modifies the switch statement indentation on php-mode?

Tags: spacemacs, indentation, php-mode

I am currently using `php-mode` with spacemacs to write in php and recently I noticed this auto-indent behavior, namely pressing `TAB`.

```php
switch ($cond) {
    case "something":
    break;
}
```

Auto indenting this region becomes

```php
switch ($cond) {
case "something":
break;
}
```

I know that in `js2-mode` for javascript a variable called `js-switch-indent-offset` do the trick, but couldn't find the one related to php so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize the indent level of the switch case for PHP like this:

```
(c-set-offset 'case-label 4)
```

This should work for any language that's based on the `c-mode`.